# Check if camera if facing a specific direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working to let a character push objects around. The problem is that as soon as he touches an object he starts moving it, even when the touch was accidental and the character isn't facing the direction of the object.

What I want to do is get the direction the object when a collision happens, and if the camara is really facing that direction allow the player to move it.

Right now I only managed to get the direction of the object, but I don't know how to compare that with the direction of the camera.

This is what I'm trying now:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    float maxOffset = 1f;
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Sol") {
        // Calculate object direction
        Vector3 direction = (col.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;

        // Check the offset with the camera rotation (this doesn't work)
        Vector3 offset = direccion - Camera.main.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.normalized;

        if(offset.x + offset.y + offset.z < maxOffset) {
             // Move the object
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve this in several different ways. And it is a bit dependent on how precise you mean *facing* the box.

You can get events when an object is visible within a certain camera, and when it enters or leaves using the following functions. With these commands from the moment the box gets rendered with that camera (so even if just a edge is visible) your collision will trigger.

[OnWillRenderObject](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.OnWillRenderObject.html), [Renderer.isVisible](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html) [Renderer.OnBecameVisible](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Renderer.OnBecameVisible.html), [OnBecameInvisible](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Renderer.OnBecameInvisible.html)

Or you could attempt to calculate whether and objects bounding box falls within the camera's view frustum, there for you could use the following geometry commands

[GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html), [GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html)

Or if you rather have a very precise *facing* you could also go for a [Physics.Raycast](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) So then you will only trigger the event when the ray is hitting the object.

Hope this helps ya out.

Answer (score 0):

Take a compass obj and align it to ur device sorry object than when you move it you can always know where it points to.

theoretically it should work but maybe your object just moves around because of a bug in your simulator motion engine.